# Spring Security Apple Sign in

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, apple-sign-in

So I am trying to use Apple Sign in with REST API within my Spring Boot backend application, everything is working fine! Until I try to access the user name, even though I ask for `name` in scope, apple seems not to send back the name, and the documentation says clearly that they don't provide a user info uri, however `AppleJS` seems to return a `user` object in the response payload

And yes, I have implemented a custom OIDC UserDetails Service.

```
    public class CompactOAuth2UserService implements OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser>
```

.

```
  security:
oauth2:
  client:
    registration:
      apple:
        clientId: id
        clientSecret: secret
        authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
        redirectUri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
        scope:
          - openid
          - name
          - email
        clientName: Apple
        clientAuthenticationMethod: post
    provider:
      apple:
        authorizationUri: https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token
        tokenUri: https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token
        jwkSetUri: https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys
        userNameAttribute: sub
```

How can I get the user name? If it is not possible what is the best practice for this?

Comment: How does your client secret work now apple enforces to use dynamic key over static client secret

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `name` scope needs to be included in a query param to the `/auth/authorize` endpoint. Then it will be included in the response as a `user` object like you mentioned. NOTE: seems, though, it will be split first and last name.

From: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118209

> To request user information in the `id_token` (assuming you are requesting via the `/auth/authorize` REST API), you'll need to include the `scope` query parameter, which supports the values—`name` and `email`. You can request one, both, or none.
>
> **Note**: Use space separation and percent-encoding for multiple scopes; for example, `"scope=name%20email"`.

Then, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms

> **Handle the Response**
>
> When the Sign in with Apple UI appears in the opened browser tab, the user can sign in and accept any terms and conditions for your app. After Apple processes the authorization request, the handling of the response depends on the value in response_mode:
>
> ...
>
> A successful response contains the following parameters:
>
> ...
> *user*
>
> - A JSON string containing the data requested in the scope property. The returned data is in the following format: { "name": { "firstName": string, "lastName": string }, "email": string }

Comment: Do you know how this will work now key/pair secret over static client secret